# Android : java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 5, size is 4

Tags: android

I'm implementing to deletion the multiple images from Grid-view on delete button click . I have put check box and image-view in Grid-View.I select multiple check box on images those images are deleted but sometime my application was crashed and getting exception of **java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 5, size is 4** at this line = **data.remove(pos);** in check box click event.How to solve this .

Here is my code in Adapter class

```
final BitmapItems item = data.get(position);
        //holder.imageTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
        holder.image.setImageBitmap(item.getBitmap());
            final int pos = position;
            Log.e("pos ", " = " + pos);

            holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.getText() + " is " + cb.isChecked(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if(cb.isChecked())
                    {
                        int checked = 1;
                        Log.e("", "" + checked);
                        String path = ((String) f.get(pos));
                        selectedFile.add(path);
                        Log.e("path ", " = " + path);
                        data.remove(pos);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int checked = 0;
                        Log.e("",""+ checked);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Here is my delete button code in Activity

```
imgDeleteImagesFromGallery = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgDeleteImage);
        imgDeleteImagesFromGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                gridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                Iterator iterator = selectedFile.iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext())
                {
                    gridFilePath = new File(iterator.next().toString());
                    if(gridFilePath.exists())
                    {
                        gridFilePath.delete();
                        Log.e("File deleted","Succesfully !!");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Here Log Cat error

```
10-14 04:16:02.635  15018-15018/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.tazeen.classnkk, PID: 15018
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 5, size is 4
            at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
            at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:403)
            at com.example.tazeen.classnkk.AddPost$GridView_Adapter$1.onClick(AddPost.java:931)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:125)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19748)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
```

Comment: Try setting the pos as position-1

Comment: Well if the size is 4, you can't remove an index at 5 , but you know that already. Likely cause is that the user might have tapped quickly twice and the second call came after the item had been removed. Just add a check for array size before the remove call

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting because the array size is 4 count start from(0-4) but the index is 5 count start from (1-5) so used this code. I have added position-1

```
final BitmapItems item = data.get(position);
        //holder.imageTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
        holder.image.setImageBitmap(item.getBitmap());
            final int pos = position;
            Log.e("pos ", " = " + pos);

            holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.getText() + " is " + cb.isChecked(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if(cb.isChecked())
                    {
                        int checked = 1;
                        Log.e("", "" + checked);
                        String path = ((String) f.get(pos));
                        selectedFile.add(path);
                        Log.e("path ", " = " + path);
                        data.remove(pos-1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int checked = 0;
                        Log.e("",""+ checked);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: I change in my code using data.remove(pos-1); and this also   final int pos = position - 1 ; but when i check the 1st position of image it will crash the app again and getting same error of java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=202; index=-1

Comment: dont put both (pos = position - 1) data.remove(pos-1); put only data.remove(pos-1); then it will work

Comment: I'm saying i tried both line first time this (pos = position - 1)  when getting error i removed and second  this data.remove(pos-1); but still getting same error of ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=202; index=-1 when i select first image of gridview means check box.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the pos as position-1, since its possible that the checkbox positions don't start at 0, but at 1. 
That would explain why the index is trying to access the array size + 1.
I believe the right place to do this would be at this line:

```
holder.image.setImageBitmap(item.getBitmap());
        final int pos = position - 1 ; //here
        Log.e("pos ", " = " + pos);
```

Comment: Can someone give me suggestions ?

Comment: @androidTag what do you mean suggestions dude? have you tried this? what was the outcome? what else have you tried?

Comment: I have tried your code .If 5 image are In grid-view and when i select first image means 0th position image app will crash.And i want to delete multi selection images from grid-view.

Comment: @androidTag In that case, before you do the critical line ´data.remove(pos);´ do an if to see if pos < array.size(), to make sure you're not going out of bounds, lets see if that fixes the issue

Comment: @androidTag Also, what object is data? Maybe instead of deleting the position I believe you can do something like data.indexOf(cb), so you could: data.remove(data.indexOf(cb)) or data.remove(data.indexOf(item))

Comment: Again same error occurre =  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=202; index=-1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92354/discussion-between-androidtag-and-victor).